# Variable in section .data is initialized to wrong value: 11264 instead of 0

Tags: variables, assembly, gdb, nasm

Given this code that just exits itself

```
section .data
zero: db 0

section .text
  global _start
_start:
  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
```

which is compiled and linked using:

```
nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf tmp.asm && ld tmp.o
```

When I debug it using `gdb`, I get the following:

```
(gdb) break _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4000b0: file tmp.asm, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, _start () at tmp.asm:7
(gdb) display zero
1: zero = 11264
```

I don't understand why zero has a value of `11264` instead of `0`. Am I messing something up?

Comment: There is no type information for `zero`, and `gdb` thought it was a 32 bit integer. Try `display/b &zero` instead.

Comment: @Jester that gave me `(gdb) display/b zero
1: x/xb zero  0x2c00: Disabling display 1 to avoid infinite recursion.
Cannot access memory at address 0x2c00`. What does that mean?

Comment: Turns out, for whatever reason, gdb wants `&zero`.  `(unsigned char)zero` also works.

Comment: @Jester that seemed to work, thanks! `x/xb &zero  0x6000c8 <zero>: 0x00`. I think my broader questions about this case are should I not be using `db`? Or perhaps alternatively, how do I get type information for `zero`?

Comment: You can use `db` if that's what your code requires. I don't think you can ask `nasm` to generate better debug info for you. Anyway, it's assembly code, you probably know what your types are, just use the proper specifiers to examine them.

Comment: @Jester one more general question...if I use db to declare a variable, should I be doing `mov al, [var]` instead of `mov rax, [var]`? The reason I ask is because with the latter, I get garbage looking values in gdb.

Comment: Yes, you should always use the proper size for your data.

Comment: you are not declaring variable, you are just reserving some memory space, and labeling it with symbolic name like `zero`, which is technically memory address of first byte of reserved space. So yes, all your code must access that address in desired way, if you use wrong access by accident, you will read more/less memory than was desired, and value will be wrong. If you designed that "variable" as `byte` type, then you must use either `mov al,[var]` or zero/sign extending movzx/movsx: `movzx eax,byte [var]` and telling them explicitly how much memory they should fetch + extend.

Comment: This also makes all kind of direct access tricks possible, like you can change any single byte value in 32b integer in memory by overwriting just particular byte, etc... Similar actions in high level typed languages usually involve whole arithmetic expression describing the calculation leading to similar result. So with asm you have full control over bits and bytes, registers and memory.. and sooooo many ways how to do a mistake while writing your code. :) .. so you need to be very precise, and always have exact plan for your data structures, being aware of each type and using correct code.